HDA Intel PCH doesn't work/show up
I'm having audio problems on ubuntu 20.04. My PCH card doesn't show under aplay-l. There are missing files for the card on proc/asound/. Previously I could select it on alsamixer and change the volume meanwhile now shows This sound device does not have any controls.

I tried copying my respective PCH files from a live cd and when I booted up on my SSD audio was available again. Hope it helps anyone.
